# Routing View from external post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm calling my MVC post method from my php website using curl.  The post method hits my API Controller which looks like this fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TransferView([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    var userid = Convert.ToInt32(data["userid"]);
    var clientid = Convert.ToInt32(data["clientid"]);

    // Rest of Code here

    return View(vm);
}
```

What isn't working is that on the return View it is using the url from the php project.  I would like to open the View in my MVC project.  Is there anyway for me to change routing to make this work or load the razor view differently?  Any help would be much appreciated.

It is returning in the URL back to my php project.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API controller method cannot return `View`. It can return only status code or `JsonResult`. So your Web API controller method should be as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethodName([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    var userid = Convert.ToInt32(data["userid"]);
    var clientid = Convert.ToInt32(data["clientid"]);

    // Rest of Code here

    return Json(yourData);
}
```

Now you can generate view in your Client side (the app consuming the web API) using the returned data.

Comment: So after I call the POST method, should I create another method, pass it my viewmodel, and return the view from that method?

Comment: Why do you need returning view? Are you not calling this post method from PHP app?

Comment: I don't want to return the view to the php app.  I'm opening up a new view in my MVC project.  I actually don't want to return anything to the PHP app.

Comment: Okay! You want to opening View in the ASP.NET MVC App  calling from the PHP App? Am I right?

Comment: Logically its not possible! Because if you want want to call a method of one app from another app then the method must be an Web API method and Web API can return only data or status code. So whatever you want to do, you have to do with the returned data.